# Cloud-based Android Development

Tags: android, ide, cloud, aide-ide

Can anyone recommend a good cloud-based IDE for Android development?

I use Eclipse/ADT on my desktop and AIDE on my Android devices, but it is a hassle to sync the two.

If there is not one available, would anyone recommend using AIDE's premium features to host my application on GIT?

Comment: Just curious, what do you currently do to get them back in sync? I was using an awkward dropbox method.. but back then AIDE just came out and I don't know if it has better dropbox support by now.

Comment: I'm using dropbox too and it works well for me. Occasionally I have some sync problems if I forget to close Eclipse on one pc and run it on the other

Comment: +1 for Dropbox. I tried Dropbox on AIDE but never thought about saving the files in my desktop Dropbox folder and importing them into Eclipse (so they sync automatically).

Comment: I have been zipping the folder & emailing it to myself. It is even more of a pain now that the Android Gmail app blocks zip attachment downloads....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I never found a good cloud-based Android IDE, but here is what I did (an idea for anyone reaching this from Google). This works with Windows, Linux, and (I think) Mac. Please confirm for others if this works for you on a Mac.

**Desktop (w/ Eclipse):**

- Set up Dropbox
- Create a new Android application project.
- Uncheck the "Create Project in Workspace" option, and change the location to your Dropbox folder

**Android (w/ AIDE):**

- Set up Dropbox sync

That's all there is to it. As long as you make sure you Dropbox before switching from desktop to Android device or vice versa, you essentially have a free, cloud-based Android IDE to develop from a desktop or an Android device.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my workflow for developing for android on android:

Setup a android build server with the android sdk, ant, Ivy Or the new Gradle setup, using 
an aws ec2 server or other free/cheap Cloud Server svc.

Setup dropbox Headless Install On That machine.

Setup A Git repo on that machine, put the repo inside Main Dropbox Directory.

```
        ---Home  
          ---(User)  
            ---Dropbox
              ---Repos
                ---App#1
```

Setup inotifywait on the dir the app repo Is In....

```
         inotifywait -mr -e ATTRIB /home/user/Dropbox/path/to/repo/ |

    while read dir ev file;
    do
    cd /home/user/Dropbox/path/to/repo;
    git pull;
    git add .;
    git commit -m " something regarding code has changed. check .... for more info";
    git push;
    buildscript;
```

Install Dropbox On Your Android Tablet

Install a text/code Editor on Your tab like .....920 Text Editor.

So Now when you Make A code change on your tab dropbox Will Sync It obviously
And That Sync Which Is An attrib event will trigger a Bunch Of Scripts...git Stuff and The Build stuff and any other Scripts You Desire.

The Final apk That The Build Script Created will Be Saved To Your app Project Directory Which is in your Dropbox so Installing/testing on Your Tab is seemless And You Can Have Others Test Your Apk By sharing That folder With them Thru dropbox

Hooking the Code to a Git Repo is Cool B/c you Can Use a service like cloudbees To then build And Test your apk. Aswell As, have the Apk sent To Distributors And other cool services.